# How to get session in UnityMvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, dependency-injection, unity-container

I want to send session to repository layer of my project because I'll want to get session for change connection of Db Context.
I have a class `UnitOfWork` in my repository that contains bellow code :

```
  public UnitOfWork(ForumContext context)
  {
      if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectionString"] != null)
      {
          context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString =
             HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectionString"].toString();
      }
      _context = context;

      ...
  }
```

Also, I have a IOC Layer for UnityMVC4.

My Problem is when I set `session["ConnectionString"]` in my controller but `HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectionString"]` is null in `UnitOfWork` of repository layer.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: My Problem is when i set session["ConnectionString"] in my controller but HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectionString"] is null in UnitOfWork of repository layer.

Comment: and where is unity? where is DI?

Comment: Why do you put the connection string in the session and why do you do this from within a controller?

Comment: Connection string is a sample, i set a key in session (ex: key is Acc ,it is mean that i should set connection of Accounting Database)and so in my repository layer call a function in my utilities layer for get connection string